# python selenium checkbox nth element if text

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using python selenium and need to reach to the element, where the label is "thisis2ndID" and enable the checkbox?

```
<h3 class="activator"> … </h3>
<div class="accordion-panel">
    <ul>
        <li class="field">
            <input id="thisis1stID" type="checkbox" name=""></input>
            <label for="thisis1stID"> … </label>
        </li>
        <li class="field">
            <input id="thisis2ndID" type="checkbox" name=""></input>
            <label for="thisis2ndID"> … </label>
        </li>
        <li class="field">
            <input id="thisis3rdID" type="checkbox" name=""></input>
            <label for="thisis3rdID"> … </label>
        </li
```

tried these but they dont seem to work...

```
    browser.find_element_by_id('main-id').click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordion-panel']")
    browser.find_element_by_id(thisis2ndID').is_selected()
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this a couple of different ways, but the best method in your case is to iterate all the `li` tags and search for the `id` value you are looking for, try this

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordion-panel']")
for i in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("li"):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is provision to find elements using cssSelector in python, the follwing selector along with click() event will enable the checkbox....

```
"div.accordion-panel li.field+li.field>#thisis2ndID"
```

I've worked only on java, so i wont be able to provide exact code in python..

[you can click here to know more about different kind of selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Answer (score 0):

this worked...sorry for the confusion, the activator needed to be clicked to load the sub options...

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('activator').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordion-panel']")
browser.find_element_by_id('thisis2ndID').click()
time.sleep(5)
```